# Measuring attitude towards learning another language?

Tags: measurement, experimental-psychology, language, survey, attitudes

Does a *validated* scale to asses a person's **attitude** towards learning a new language exist?

So far I have only found the following questionnaires:

- [Language Learning Attitudes Questionnaire](http://www-01.sil.org/lingualinks/languagelearning/prepareforlanguagelearning/attitude.pdf)
- [Readiness for Language Learning Questionnaire](http://paul-timothy.net/pages/language/Currah%20language%20learning%20attitude%20survey.pdf)
- [Foreign Language Classroom Anxiety Scale (FLCAS)](http://www.publicacions.ub.edu/revistes/bells12/pdf/art11.pdf)
- [Attitude/Motivation Test Battery (AMTB)](http://publish.uwo.ca/~gardner/docs/englishamtb.pdf)
- [Second Language Tolerance of Ambiguity Scale (SLTAS)](http://www.leeds.ac.uk/arts/download/1320/kazamia1999)

Comment: Nice question. I edited the question a bit, and in particular I removed the reference to "aptitude" in the title since only attitude was mentioned in the body (in bold), and they are essentially two different questions.

Comment: The question of attitude towards learning anything involves the question of motivation in the subject too among other things.  This is a little broad and I don't think this can be assessed by one questionaire and scale.